# What is the difference between first and second version of the constructor

Tags: c++, list-initialization

The first **1** version works correct. But why doesn't the code work with the second **2** version?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Synchronized {
public:
  Synchronized(T initial = T())
  {
      value = move(initial);
  };

  struct Access {
      T& ref_to_value;
      lock_guard<mutex> l;

// 1      Access(T& _value, mutex& _m): ref_to_value(_value), l(_m) {};
// 2      Access(): ref_to_value(value), l(m) {};
  };

  Access GetAccess()
  {
// 1     return {value, m};
// 2     return {};
// 3     return {value, lock_guard(m)};
  }

private:
    T value;
    mutex m;
};
```

The errors I receive are:

```
>error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Synchronized<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value'

>error: invalid use of non-static data member 'Synchronized<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::m'
```

The default constructor **3** also works correct.

Comment: `value` and `m` are members of `Synchronized`, not `Access` so the second version has no idea what to variables are.

Comment: there are some wrong assumptions about nested classes. I suppose in other languages they work very different. In C++ its mainly about using  `Synchronized::Access` vs `Access` not much more

Comment: Did you work with Java before. This would work in java, but C++ nested classes are the equivalent of static inner classes in java.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from subtle differences that are not relevant here, your code is equivalent to:

```
template <typename T>
struct Access {
    T& ref_to_value;
    lock_guard<mutex> l;
    Access(): ref_to_value(value), l(m) {};
};

template <typename T>
class Synchronized {
public:
  Synchronized(T initial = T())
  {
      value = move(initial);
  };
  Access GetAccess()
  {
     return {};
  }

private:
    T value;
    mutex m;
};
```

In `Access()` there is no `value` nor `m`. If you want to use them as arguments to the constructor then you must write the constructor as you did with `(1)`.